# How to get rid of 403 Forbidden error on WordPress root folder on MAMP server

Tags: wordpress, apache, localhost, mamp

I have had major problems installing MAMP.

It installed without any problems, and I can get to the MAMP welcome page, phpMyAdmin page, and everything else at `http://localhost:8888/MAMP/?language=English`.

I can also access a static test page in a test folder in the document root (`/Users/username/Hosting/test/test.html`).

However, when I try to access anything in the WordPress Document root that I imported from my live site (`/Users/username/Hosting/wordpress`) I get a 403 Forbidden error.

I checked the apache error log, and this is what is showing up when I try and access anything in the WordPress folder:

`[Fri May 03 08:59:10 2013] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /Users/reae/Hosting/wordpress/wp-admin`

I am on day 2 trying to work this out. I have uninstalled and reinstalled MAMP multiple times, and tried everything that I can think of to fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I had a hidden .htaccess file in my wordpress folder.

Removed that and everything was fine.

Comment: how do I find the same?